# Flutter: How to create an xy grid to position icons exactly where needed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a moving horizontal slider that tracks "progress" of a task, and above the slider I want to position icons that indicate certain milestones at the point of the progress.  So far I have tried using the TimelineTile widget to move the slider:

```
Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 50,
    ),
    width: screenWidth,
    child: TimelineTile(
        axis: TimelineAxis.horizontal,
        alignment: TimelineAlign.end,
        indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle(
        indicatorXY: currProgress / 1.0, //currProgress is a double from 0.0 to 1.0 updated by a setState elsewhere in the code
        ),
    ),
),
```

I know I can wrap this in a column, and put a row above it with a series of SizedBoxes and Icons but that is inaccurate and very unfluttery to be able to position a dynamic number of icons and their positions from a database, e.g..

```
child: Row(
    children: [
        SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth * .2,
        ),
        Icon(Icon(Icons.email,
            color: Colors.purple),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: screenWidth * .35),
        Icon(Icon(Icons.email,
            color: Colors.purple),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: screenWidth * .2),
    ],
),
```

I have looked into gridview, but it seems that needs every grid to be filled, so that would not work.
I have looked into google charts and syncfusion cartesian charts, which would allow me to position points on a two-row double-based grid such as (0.2,0.0) and (0.35,1.0) but they are very clunky and overly complicated for this, and don't seem to allow icons other than simple circles and such but someone may know better than me.

And lastly I am trying [LayoutGrid package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_layout_grid) perhaps with the FixedTrackSize option to create a grid at a very small resolution, which I could live with if it is imperceptible to the user that the icon is position at 0.3 or 0.4 (let's the resolution is tenths) while the data actually show 0.34 or 0.41 as an example.

I hope that makes sense.  That is a lot of writing to say I just want a 2 rows of information:
a. a dot that moves along the screen horizontally that is incremented by a setState of the variable (currProgress in the timelineTile example above, but maybe I don't need to use timelineTime if some kind of grid will work).  and,
b. another row that displays a list of icons read from a database dynamically, where you do not know until data read what the list is.  So an example list of data could be:
//Icon,        Position
Icons.email,    x=.35
Icons.airplane, x=.54
etc.
where x=0.0 to 1.0 but could live with some reasonable level of resolution that is not exactly to double precision, as long as it looks very close on the app screen.

Thank you, you are all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<IconData> stageIcons = [
    Icons.send,
    Icons.email,
    Icons.done
  ];

  double curProgress = -1.0;
  final iconSize = 20.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: iconSize, vertical: iconSize),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 5,
                value: curProgress,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: 
                List.generate(stageIcons.length, (index) { // hack, like list.map((element, index) {...})
                  double stageProgress;
                  if (index == 0) {
                    stageProgress = 0.0;
                  } else if (index == stageIcons.length) {
                    stageProgress = 1.0;
                  } else {
                    stageProgress = (1 / (stageIcons.length - 1)) * index;
                  }
                  print("$curProgress $stageProgress ${(stageProgress >= curProgress)}");
                  final iconColor = (stageProgress <= curProgress) ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue[100];
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    radius: iconSize,
                    backgroundColor: iconColor,
                    child: Icon(stageIcons[index], color: Colors.white, size: iconSize),
                  );
                }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: 
          (curProgress > 0.0 && curProgress < 1.0) ? null // disable button if in progress
          : () async {
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
              await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
              setState(() {
                curProgress = i / 10;
              });
            }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo app image]

Update. Custom progress/position

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class Stage {
  final double progress;
  final IconData icon;
  
  Stage(this.progress, this.icon);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<Stage> stages = [
    Stage(0.0, Icons.send),
    Stage(0.71, Icons.email),
    Stage(1.0, Icons.done)
  ];

  double curProgress = -1.0;
  final iconSize = 20.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            [Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: iconSize, vertical: iconSize),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 5,
                value: curProgress,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
              ),
            )],
            List.generate(stages.length, (index) { // hack, like list.map((element, index) {...})
              final stage = stages[index];
              final iconColor = (stage.progress <= curProgress) ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue[100];
              final position = stage.progress * 2 - 1; // progress from 0.0 to 1.0 and Align.position from -1.0 to 1.0 from center
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment(position, 0.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: iconSize,
                  backgroundColor: iconColor,
                  child: Icon(stage.icon, color: Colors.white, size: iconSize),
                )
              );
            })
          ].expand((el) => el).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: 
          (curProgress > 0.0 && curProgress < 1.0) ? null // disable button if in progress
          : () async {
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
              await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
              setState(() {
                curProgress = i / 10;
              });
            }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The LinearProgressIndicator is a much cleaner option than the timelineTile I had been using, so +1 for that.  To my understanding of your code, the functionality this does not accomplish is the ability to position icons anywhere along the linearProgressIndicator.  For example, is it possible to position the email icon at a progress of .71?

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: Thanks so much.  That's it!

Comment: Is it bad stackoverflow form to ask another question related to this?  Can I add a method that runs when curProgress reaches >= stage.progress?  Perhaps have it be part of the Stage class so each instance of state in <stages> has its own method that is set in the declaration of stages?

Comment: Sure. For example, you can declare function `Function onProgress` in Stage class, instantiate it `Stage(0.71, Icons.email, () {return true;})` and run it where necessary with `stage.onProgress()`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Can I ask, is it possible for the function onProgress to be async and fetch data from the cloud?  In particular I want to play an audiofile from url, but the build method using List.generate above is not async.  When I try to use async and await in that code where needed, it breaks the class I use to call this class in it's build method (which is in a seperate .dart file), I think because that build method is not async and just builds immediately without waiting for this class you wrote to complete it's async tasks.